# Which toolchain should I use to build Substrate

Tags: rust, cargo, versioning

My current toolchains and targets look like this

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-2022-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
```

Should I use `stable` or `nightly`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: you likely should use the latest of both stable and nightly when building Substrate chains at any given time. Update regularly with `rustup update`.**

It is quite likely the toolchain you *should* use for a given tag/release of Substrate (like `polkadot-v0.9.19`) is best discovered in the:

- [release notes of Polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.19),
- Polkadot release *branch* [`nix.sh`
  configuration](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.19/shell.nix#L8) in the Substrate,
- or the [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L41) target
  [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/paritytech/ci-linux/tags?page=1&name=production) used to do regular builds (matching the Substrate version you are using to the version of the image) and inspect it's nightly version.

You need *both* the stable and nightly, specifically nightly for the Wasm build, that is required for now (but [not forever](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/1252) we expect).